# Theoretical Otto and Brayton cycles are reversible and have efficiency less than the Carnot efficiency, so appear to violate 2nd law. Help

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I understand Carnot's theorem, specifically the result that "the efficiency of all reversible engines operating between the same two temperatures is the same." The proof is by contradiction and you can find it all over the web.

However, the theoretical Otto or Brayton cycles are reversible, and have efficiency less than the Carnot efficiency. I've gone through the efficiency calculation myself for Otto, and got the same result that is all over the web. Indeed, one can construct all sorts of theoretical reversible cycles which are less efficient than Carnot.

I do not understand the existence of reversible cycles with efficiency less than Carnot. If they exist, even in theory, we could run the output from a Carnot engine into one of them (say, a Brayton or Otto heat pump), and move heat continually from a cold reservoir into a hot one with no external input.

Indeed, this is exactly the contradiction at the center of Carnot's theorem leading to its main result, that all reversible processes have the same efficiency. Even worse, the more inefficient the non-Carnot process (which we turned into a heat pump), the more we violate the second law of thermodynamics.

To put numbers on it, say $T_\text{hot} = 400 \ \text{K}$ and $T_\text{cold} = 300 \ \text{K}$, so the Carnot efficiency is 0.25. Our Carnot engine is turning 1000 W of input heat into 250 W of work and discharging 750 W into the cold reservoir. If the 250 Watts of work is running a heat pump, a reversed cycle which would have had engine efficiency 0.1, then the heat pump is drawing 2250 W of heat out of the cold reservoir and discharging 2500 W into the hot one. The result is 1500 Watts being transferred from the cold reservoir to the hot one with no external input. Obviously impossible.

The issue seems to be that reversing the inefficient engine creates a really efficient heat pump. So I know that's where the error lies, but not exactly what the error is. Can anyone clarify?

Comment: Please tell more about the reversed cycle.

Comment: Hello Dennis. I've updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reversible Otto and Brayton cycles don’t operate between two fixed temperature reservoirs as does the Carnot cycle. That makes them less efficient.

Regarding your statement:

> "The efficiency of all reversible engines operating between the same
> two temperatures is the same."

The key point is the reversible cycle has to operate between two ***fixed*** temperature reservoirs. The Otto and Brayton cycles do not operate between two fixed temperature reservoirs. They operate between a series of reservoirs between the maximum and minimum temperatures.

The Carnot efficiency is

$$\eta =1-\frac{T_L}{T_H}$$

Where $T_H$ is a single high temperature reservoir where all heat is taken from and $T_L$ is a single low temperature reservoir where all heat is rejected.

For the Otto and Brayton cycles $T_H$ is replaced by $T_{Hm}$ where $T_{Hm}$ is the mean temperature at which heat is taken in.  That value is less than $T_H$.

Then $T_L$ is replaced by $T_{Lm}$ where $T_{Lm}$ is the mean temperature  at which heat is rejected. That value is always greater than $T_L$ of the Carnot cycle.

So if you plug in the mean high and low temperatures of the Otto and Brayton cycles into the Carnot efficiency equation you will find that the efficiency is always less than the Carnot efficiency.

I have provided TS diagrams of the idealized reversible Otto and Brayton cycles gas cycles with that of the Carnot Cycle, for both heat engines and reverse heat engines, in case they may be of help to you.

> The issue seems to be that reversing the inefficient engine creates a
> really efficient heat pump. So I know that's where the error lies, but
> not exactly what the error is. Can anyone clarify?

In fact, a less efficient heat engine does make a more "efficient" heat pump, and vice versa. This may see counter intuitive until you look at it closely. Consider the following:

First, the “efficiency” of the heat pump is actually called its Coefficient of Performance (COP) and equals the heat delivered to the high temperature environment divided by the work required. In your example, it would be 2500/250 = 10. If your reverse your heat pump cycle to make it a reversible heat engine cycle the efficiency of the heat engine would be 0.1. This means the relationship between the COP of the heat pump (HP) and the efficiency of the heat engine (HE) is

$$COP_{HP}=\frac{1}{\eta _{HE}}$$

Which gives the interesting, but important, result that the lower the efficiency of the heat engine the greater the COP of the heat engine when operating in reverse as a heat pump, and vice versa.  As I said, this may seem counter intuitive until you look at it closely.

You know the efficiency of a reversible heat engine cycle is greater the larger the difference in temperature between the high and low temperature reservoirs. The greater that difference in temperature, the more output work you get for the same heat input.

On the other hand, for the heat pump the greater the difference in temperature the more work is required to move the same amount of heat from the low temperature environment to the high temperature environment. It’s kind of the equivalent of pulling a weight up a hill. The higher the hill, the more work required to move the same weight up the hill. Or, to put it another way, moving heat from a low temperature to a high temperature is not a natural thing, just like things don’t naturally roll up hill. It takes work. And the greater the temperature difference the harder it is (the more work required) to move the same amount of heat.

This is one of the reasons that heat pumps are used primarily in temperate climates where the difference between the indoor and outdoor temperature is not too great.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Hmm... I understand this, although the intermediate temperatures along the non-isothermal processes are completely determined (in theory) by the thermodynamic equations of state (and may be expressed only in terms of T_hot and T_cold). I also understand that the existence of non-isothermal, non-adiabatic processes in the cycle would make it hard to construct in practice with only two heat reservoirs. That said, strictly in theory, we could still consider the reverse of a less-than-Carnot efficient engine, that would create a super heat pump and violate the theorem. Or where does that go wrong?

Comment: @Dennis Not sure I follow you. The point is the two cycles in question take in heat over a range of temperatures between a max and min  and reject heat over a range of temperatures between a max and min, whereas the Carnot cycle takes in all its heat at a single high temperature and rejects all its heat at a single low temperature.  That's what makes it the most efficient reversible cycle.

Comment: Bob, my problem is not that there exist cycles which are less efficient than Carnot. It is that, if I manage to reverse one of these cycles, it will create a heat pump that is more efficient than a Carnot heat pump. This super heat pump, in combination with a Carnot engine, would violate the Carnot theorem and 2nd law of thermo. So it must be impossible. Yet, online it is repeatedly stated that idealized Otto or Brayton cycles (among many others) are reversible. What gives?

Comment: @Dennis Do you realize that efficiency of a heat pumps is its Coefficient of Performance (COP).?

Comment: Yes, I understand the COP. However, going back to the example in my question where we fed the output work of a Carnot engine into a "super" heat pump that was an inverted Otto or Brayton cycle, the COP is not what would determine the heat flow from the cold reservoir to the hot reservoir. If the Otto cycle had, for example, 10% efficiency (depends on the volumes) as an engine, the reversed cycle would pull 2250 W from the cold reservoir using the 250 W of input work. You can work through the nuts and bolts details on a PV diagram, like a HW set. It violates Carnot's theorem.

Comment: The thing to focus on is that Carnot's theorem states that all reversible cycles have the same efficiency. Then elsewhere, people all seem to say the Otto and Brayton cycles are reversible. Yet they have lower efficiency, in direct violation of the Carnot theorem. That is the central issue.

Comment: @Dennis Carnot's There are too many issues with your last two comments to address in the comment format. I will attempt to revise my answer one more time to address them, but if that doesn't work I'm finished.

Comment: @Dennis "If the Otto cycle had, for example, 10% efficiency (depends on the volumes) as an engine, the reversed cycle would pull 2250 W from the cold reservoir using the 250 W of input work". How exactly did you come up with 2250 W from the cold reservoir? In the example in your post, the reverse Carnot cycle would pull 750 W from the cold reservoir not 2250 W and deposit 1000 W in the hot reservoir, not 2500 W. Where are you getting these numbers from?

Comment: @Dennis In particular, what do you mean by 0.1 efficiency in your example. What is the equation? I think this is where you are making a conceptual error. If you cannot answer this for me I can't help you any further and will have to abandon this effort.

Comment: Ah, I think I see the issue. In the reversed Otto cycle, the heat is exhausted in the isochor, which runs between TH and T2. So I can't use the same TH from the Carnot cycle, but instead have to use T2 for the hot reservoir temp. Similarly the heat is drawn in between TC and the other intermediate temperature, so it's the intermediate temp which must equal the Carnot TC. Hmm. I will have to redo the calculation trying to made the intermediate temps for the Otto equal to the hot and cold temps of the Carnot. I imagine that will make the Carnot output less work and fix the issue

Comment: Thank you for your help and patience. Think your revised answer is great.

Comment: @Dennis I think you may be on the right track, but since you didn't provide a diagram, it's difficult for me to know what $T_H$, $T_2$ and $T_C$ are. I have added TS diagrams to my answer. If, after you review your concepts and calculations, you would like me to take a look at, then update your post. It would be helpful if you could use the. same parameters as in the diagrams I have provided, to facilitate further discussion. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. Comparing to your helpful diagram of the Otto cycle, my TC is your T1, my TH is your T3, my T2 is your T2. I actually disagree with you that heat could be rejected in the Otto heat pump at T_Hm. This is isochoric cooling caused only by temperature difference, and the flow would not occur in the portion of the isochor where the reservoir temperature did not allow it. Instead, the hot reservoir must be at T2, the coldest point along the isochor. Similarly the cold reservoir must be at T4 (your diagram) in order for this heat flow in the Otto pump to occur. (Continues)

Comment: If I recalculate the work output of the Carnot cycle running between T2 and T4, and then calculate how much heat could be pumped back into the hot reservoir by an Otto cycle using this work, the 2nd law is no longer violated.

Comment: My error was not realizing that flow could not occur in an Otto heat pump trying to take in Q at TC and reject it at TH.  The engine, by contrast, can do this, using combustion and temperature difference to generate its Q_in and Q_out respectively.

Comment: @Dennis “… Instead, the hot reservoir must be at T2, the coldest point along the isochor”.

Comment: No.  Remember we are talking about a reversible cooling process. That means the temperature of the high temperature reservoir must be infinitesimally lower than the temperature of the gas at each equilibrium point of the isochor between points 3 and 2.  This requires an infinite series of high temperature reservoirs ranging between T3 and T2, each being infinitesimally lower than the preceding reservoir and each infinitesimally lower than the gas temperature at each equilibrium state.

Comment: In effect, the overall heat transfer occurs at some mean value between T3 and T2.  If all the heat transfer from the gas occurred at T2, the cooling process would be irreversible.

Comment: “…Similarly the cold reservoir must be at T4 (your diagram) in order for this heat flow in the Otto pump to occur”. No again, for the same reason. If all the heat transfer occurred at T4 the heat transfer process would be irreversible. To be reversible the difference in temperature between the gas and the surroundings has to be infinitesimal at each equilibrium point along the process curve.

Comment: “If I recalculate the work output of the Carnot cycle running between T2 and T4, and then calculate how much heat could be pumped back into the hot reservoir by an Otto cycle using this work, the 2nd law is no longer violated.” There is no second law violation. I will attempt to revise my answer to show why.

Comment: “My error was not realizing that flow could not occur in an Otto heat pump trying to take in Q at TC and reject it at TH. The engine, by contrast, can do this, using combustion and temperature difference to generate its Q_in and Q_out respectively”. The first sentence is correct. The heat transfers do not occur at two single temperatures. Not sure what the second sentence means.

Comment: Well, Bob, since we're still discussing this... an Otto engine accomplishes its isochoric heating (2 to 3 in your diagram) by combusting gas inside the chamber. This is not reversible. The isochoric cooling (3 to 2) in the heat pump may be done in a reversible way, as you describe (constantly changing the outside T to just under the chamber T); or it may be done by keeping the outside at T_2 and having the chamber cool naturally. Whether this step is done in the "reversible" way, or the "irreversible" way, is irrelevant to the theoretical calculation of Q in or out for this step. (continues)

Comment: So I don't understand why you are mandating that we perform the isochoric cooling in the Otto heat pump in this special, very difficult way of constantly changing the outside T; while the Otto engine is, apparently, still allowed to combust gas in order to heat the air in the chamber. We are just talking on a theoretical level here. I do concede that it's *possible* to cool the air in the Otto heat pump as you describe; but this is not what I was trying to examine when I first started, which is heat being drawn in or rejected from a large outside reservoir at a constant T.

Comment: @Dennis "Well, Bob, since we're still discussing this... an Otto engine accomplishes its isochoric heating (2 to 3 in your diagram) by combusting gas inside the chamber. This is not reversible". You have got to be kidding. I have thought all along we were talking about ideal reversible cycles, not real combustion engines. Any cycle can be "reversed" but that doesn't make it a reversible cycle.  A reversible cycle generates no entropy. I have had enough. You are free to withdraw your ACCEPT. Goodbye.

Comment: Bob, I'm sorry to have made you frustrated. Your answer was good. I was talking about a cycle that could be reversed, the whole time. I didn't understand the difference between this and a "reversible" cycle. I guess don't care whether the Otto cycle is reversible, in the strict sense. My issue was that by reversing it, it appeared to be theoretically possible to take heat from a cold reservoir to a hot one constantly without work input. Thanks to your answer I see my error. I only wanted two reservoirs, as in the Carnot theorem.

Comment: @Dennis OK Dennis. I kind of thought you might not have understood the difference between a reversible cycle, which is comprised of all reversible processes, and reversing a cycle, which can be done regardless of whether or not the processes that comprise the cycle are reversible. You can have an irreversible cycle operating between two fixed reservoirs but, per Carnot's theorem, it will be less efficient than the Carnot cycle because of the generation of entropy. Sorry for losing patience. All is well.

Comment: Yes, and, incidentally, this all helped my answer another of my nagging doubts, which was why steps like isochors and isotherms were described everywhere as reversible when there is typically a nonzero dS in them. Now I see how that could work, if the correct temperature was maintained during the whole process. Thanks again and all the best.

Comment: @Dennis I've updated my answer to more directly answer the last question of your post. I hope you find it useful.

Answer (score -4):

Because you don't consider entropy. In reality, things are not the same as in the theoretical formulas. Principle I puts an equivalence between different sizes - state and process. Principle II comes with a supplement that takes into account reality. The Carnot cycle is an ideal one. Otto is real.

Comment: "In reality, things are not the same as theoretical formulas". I'm sorry, but ... are you kidding me? The Carnot theorem is a theoretical statement about idealized processes. We can just as easily discuss a theoretical Otto cycle as a theoretical Carnot cycle, as is done in countless websites and class materials available online. I understand very well that entropy increases in any real-world process. The question was, since there seem to exist reversible cycles whose efficiency is less than Carnot, why don't they violate the theorem by implying the existing of extremely efficient heat pumps?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't make sense of your answer. Perhaps you can elaborate to help me out.